# storing money amounts in mysql

Tags: mysql, floating-point, currency, fixed-point

I want to store 3.50 into a mysql table. I have a float that I store it in, but it stores as 3.5, not 3.50. How can I get it to have the trailing zero?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Do not store money values as float, use the DECIMAL or NUMERIC type:

[Documentation for MySQL Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)

EDIT & clarification:

Float values are vulnerable to rounding errors are they have limited precision so unless you do not care that you only get 9.99 instead of 10.00 you should use DECIMAL/NUMERIC as they are fixed point numbers which do not have such problems.

Answer (score 39):

It's not generally a good idea to store money as a float as rounding errors can occurr in calculations.

Consider using DECIMAL(10,2) instead.

Comment: Even the numbers like 0.1 and 0.2 are impossible to represent in binary floating point, no matter what the precision is.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 20):

Does it really matter if it stores is as 3.5, 3.50 or even 3.500?

What is really important is how it is displayed after it is retrieved from the db.

Or am I missing something here?

Also don't use a float, use a decimal.  Float has all sorts of rounding issue and isn't very big.

Comment: I do mention the rounding issue. My point was he shouldn't be worrying about how it is stored but how it is displayed.  You wouldn't store financial information to 2 decimal places - exchange rates are to 5 and we store to 6 but only display as 2.

Comment: (deleted previous irrelevant comment).  +1 for good point on rounding.

Answer (score 18):

To store values you can use a **DECIMAL(10,2)** field, then you can use the [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(`price`, 2) FROM `table` WHERE 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use DECIMAL or NUMERIC types, you can declare them as for example DECIMAL(18, 2) which would force 2 decimals even if they were 0. Depending on how big values you expect you can change the value of the first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to store "3.50" into your database?  3.5 == 3.50 == 3.5000 as far as the database is concerned.

Your presentation and formatting of figures/dates/etc should be done in the application, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

Binary can't accurately represent floating points with only a limited number of bits. It's not so muuch loss of data but actually conversion errors..
[Here's the manual giving examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)

*You can see this in action in your browser, see for yourself in this code snippet.*

```html
<script>

    var floatSum = 0;

    // add 0.1 to floatSum 10 times
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        floatSum += 0.1;
    }

    // if the repetative adding was correct, the floatSum should be equal to 1
    var expectedSum = 10*0.1; // 1

    // you can see that floatSum does not equal 1 because of floating point error
    document.write(expectedSum + " == " + floatSum + " = " + (expectedSum==floatSum) + "<br />");


    // --- using integers instead ---
    // Assume the example above is adding £0.10 ten times to make £1.00
    // With integers, we will use store money in pence (100 pence (also written 100p) in £1)

    var intSum = 0;

    // add 0.1 to floatSum 10 times
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        intSum += 10;
    }

    // if the repetative adding was correct, the floatSum should be equal to 1
    var expectedSum = 10*10; // 100

    // you can see that floatSum does not equal 1 because of floating point error
    document.write(expectedSum + " == " + intSum + " = " + (expectedSum==intSum) + "<br />");
    document.write("To display as &pound; instead of pence, we can divide by 100 (presentation only) : &pound;" + intSum/100 + "<br />");
</script>
```