# mysql error 1264 out of range value for column

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql workbench to management my database (mysql). I need to store a integer value that have more than 20 digits (we have 21 digits). I try to save in Bigint format but its not solve and i'm getting the same error:

```
mysql error 1264 out of range value for column
```

What is the best solution to save one integer with 21 digits?

Comment: try to store it as float of double

Comment: BIGINT(21) doesnt mean you can save a INT with 21 digits.. read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql

Comment: @rrpik93 I have updated my answer

Comment: @rrpik You can make use of decimal datatype.

Comment: Thanks for the replys ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of decimal datatype

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:

M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)

D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Based on answer 
[MySQL: Size of decimal data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201266/mysql-size-of-decimal-data-type)

Comment: Thanks for the replys ;)