# Mysql (using putty) how I write code for numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, database, putty

My apology with my English. I am currently trying to create a database in putty, for words we use varchar, but what about if we want to insert number? for example i am creating a car database which include the year of the making, the price, the making and the model of the car.

What is the correct syntax for price, i didn't do the right code for it as i receive an error?

Thanks!

this is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
  cars_id int(10) UNSIGNED not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  make VARCHAR(25) not null,
  model VARCHAR(25) not null,
  price(value) null float,
  yom varchar(25) not null
);
```

Comment: MySQL provides a number of numeric types - each designed for storing different sized numbers. Docs are at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html. For example: price INT, yom TINYINT

Comment: For money data use NUMERIC or DECIMAL.See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks guys, help me a lot, i will have to check mysql manual more often.

Answer (score 0):

For storing prices you *do **not*** want to use a FLOAT. They are reliant on rounding and can have variable precision based on your system's hardware and/or software configuration.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Prices have a *fixed* decimal which is why you need a fixed decimal data type like `DECIMAL`.

To declare a `DECIMAL` column you'll need to specify the total number of digits, and the number of decimal places you'd like.

eg: to store $199.95 the column would need to be `DECIMAL(5,2)`.

These are essentially stored as an integer `19995` and the decimal point is added in on retrieval. In this way you do not need to worry about gaining/losing cents randomly due to floating point precision issues.

Answer (score -1):

For Float Types, you have to specify the *total* number of digits max, and the number of digits on the right of the decimal, separated by a comma. So, for the highest price of 999999.99 you would specify:

`price FLOAT(8,2) NULL`

Which means 8 digits total, 2 to the right of the decimal.

If you have cars in the millions (eg, 1378599.99), then we would need `price FLOAT(9,2) NULL`.

Comment: so for price it would be price(9,2) null?

Comment: My bad, I totally fell for your price(value) scheme. Fixed now lol.

Comment: **Do not use FLOAT for storing prices!** You will randomly gain/lose cents/fractions of a currency unit. [Floating point numbers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html) are imprecise and rely on rounding. Use [`DECIMAL(9,2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) where mySQL will store an *integer* values with *no rounding* and present it with a decimal in the proper place.

Comment: Well, thanks for the down-vote, Sammitch. While you're right, the OP did ask about syntax, not preferred type.