# How to store currency values with commas in them?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

How to store currency values with commas in them? I'm working with phpMyAdmin with mySQL and Apache to make a database and I need to enter currency values with commas in them and also % values. Is there a datatype other than Varchar that I could use? BTW I'm very new to Php and SQL so don't yell at me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql) - short answer is `DECIMAL(10,2)`

Comment: Don't do it: store numbers properly with a decimal point; and only add % or change decimal point to decimal comma for display purposes: note that monetary values are best stored as integer rather than float

Comment: @FDL thanks I didn't realize there was another form probably because I didn't specify that I wanted to store money values in my question

Comment: `How to store currency values with commas in them?` sounds like you're specifying money values to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$You could replace commas (,) with points (.) and use the data type float/double. This only works ofcourse if you do not use commas as 1k seperators.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$numP = str_replace(",", ".", $numC);
```

You can explicitly parse the number afterwards.

```
$numF = floatval($numP);
```

doubleval() is an alias. I do not know if this is best practice, but it works.
however, you should not use this for financial applications.

Comment: How would I store the value if I am using commas as 1k separators should I just delete them completely? Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: separators for thousands are not part of the number, they're formatting for display purposes.... remove them.... if you have commas as both thousands separators and as a decimal separator, then you have much more of a problem