# Mysql, the last decimal zero disappears in Float data type for product prices

Tags: php, mysql, types, decimal

So I have a mysql database in my PhpMyAdmin which stores all the information about a big list of products. The name, description, the image file name and the price. So here is the case, some products have decimal numbers in their price so I set the datatype for productprice from int to float. But some products cost for instance, 199.90, as I enter that value in the table it receives it and stores it as 199.90 just as I want it to. But when I output the price on the website which I do with php it only outputs the number 199.9 as you can see the last zero is missing. Even though the two numbers are of the same value. 199.9 looks much less appealing  than 199.90, and I hope that is understandable. So, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: If you want to enforce 2 decimal places, then use [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) when you echo the value

Answer (score 1):

You can use number formatting in PHP:

```
  $Text = number_format($Amount,$Decimals,$DecimalSeperator,$ThousandsSeperator);
```

But remember that floats are not always the best type for storing prices. Normally prices are stored in cents in integers. The answer to the sum `100 - 50` is a definate `50`, but the answer to `1.00 - 0.50` might be `0.499999999999999`. This is just a simple example, it gets worse with more complicated calculation. A float is ok, as long as storing a price is the only thing you do. See also: [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)