# Error in JDBC code calling a stored function which returns a value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, stored-functions, callable-statement

I'm trying to print the returned value of a MySQL stored *function* from the JDBC code which is as follows (I am using MySQL Server 5.7.13):

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CallableStatementsCallingFunctions {
    public static void main(String... syrt)
    {
      try
     {
        try
        {                
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
          System.out.println("Error(class): "+ e);
        }
        try
        {
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/collablestatement","root","mysql") ;
         CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call ?:=getBalance1(?)}");
         String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
         cs.registerOutParameter(1,Types.INTEGER);
         cs.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(s));             
         cs.execute();
         System.out.println("Account number :" + cs.getInt(1));
         conn.close();
        } 
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
          System.out.println("Error(SQL) : "+e);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Error(Fro outer try) : "+ e);
    }
}
```

}

the stored function `getBalance1(acno)` is shown here

[image: getBalance(acno numeric)]

my code output is shown here

[image: jdbc output]

I am getting the output from the SQL command but in JDBC I am getting and `SQLException` saying that

> parameter 1 is not an output parameter

I know that parameter 1 has been used as the placeholder of the returned value from the function in jdbc code. In `prepareCall` I also tried the syntax -  `{?:= call getBalance1(?)}` , but  even then getting the same Exception.

Why am I getting the exception?

Comment: a quick guess is cs.getString("1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think I was  getting the SQLException because I am using jdk1.8.xx in which the syntax of calling the stored function is different. The problem was solved by replacing statement

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call ?:=getBalance1(?)}");
```

in the code with

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{? = call getBalance1(?)}");
```

The syntax of calling the function in the prepareCall() method as parameter is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

Comment: I don't think the syntax has changed in any way in Java 8. You simply had a typo (extra colon + misplaced `call` keyword) in your original statement.

Answer (score 1):

`getBalance1()` is a MySQL `FUNCTION`, not a `PROCEDURE`, so I wouldn't expect using a JDBC `CallableStatement` to be applicable.

Even in your MySQL console test you are using

```sql
select getBalance1(103)
```

so you simply need to do the same thing in your Java code using a `PreparedStatement`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select getBalance1(?)");
ps.setInt(1) = 103;
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
Double bal = rs.getDouble(1);
```

(It should be noted that since "balance" apparently refers to "money", `REAL` is not a good choice for the column type; details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13030368/2144390).)

Comment: I am getting what you have written here.But then what would the CallableStatement interface be used for if I used PreparedStatement instead?? I am trying to get the results using CallableStatement as I may get dozens of problems to face then.

Comment: The `CallableStatement` is JDBC's way of running Stored Procedures, which are created in MySQL using `CREATE PROCEDURE` and invoked in MySQL using `CALL procedurename`. You have used `CREATE FUNCTION` to create a user-defined function, which is normally invoked by including it in an expression, e.g., as part of a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Actually, you can also call SQL `FUNCTION`s with `CallableStatement`s. The JDBC syntax for this is `myConnection.prepareCall("{? = call my_function(?)}");`, as is exemplified in the answer authored by the OP.