# mySQLi Select number when contains white space

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select from table where price is >= 3000 when the field type is string and the numbers are formatted as: 3 000, 20 000, 5 000...

```
'SELECT * FROM products WHERE price >= 3000'
```

Is there a way to format it on the fly to remove the space and keep the results output as the original?

Comment: Firstly you should ask yourself why the field type is string at all if it's only going to contain numbers...

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql

Comment: @MarkPhillips it's just for readability, I know it's must be any type of INT

Comment: @medk or a type of Numeric which would be better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql

Comment: @medk You might want to do that in PHP, using [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE REPLACE(price, ' ', '') > 3000
```

But you should really change the type of your column.