# MySQL - IN - With float number - return NULL

Tags: mysql

I want to do this select, but always return NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM world.country c WHERE c.LifeExpectancy IN (45.2,46.2)
```

When I do separate selects, works fine:

**select * from world.country c where c.LifeExpectancy IN (45.2)**

**select * from world.country c where c.LifeExpectancy IN (46.2)**

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: What type of data is in column `LifeExpectancy`?  Using floating numbers is unwise as they're er, floating, and non-specific. You should be using **DECIMAL** and **CAST**ing the number to a decimal type so both values are the same type.

Comment: LifeExpectancy is float(3,1).

Comment: Right, change your float column to `Decimal` data type.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594333/mysql-compare-float-numbers-ignored