# Equivalent of Money in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, currency

How do I convert the following SQL statement into MySQL. Is there a equivalent for money in MySQL ?

```
 DECLARE v_min_msrp int;
  DECLARE  v_avg_msrp int;
  DECLARE v_max_msrp int;

  SELECT 
    Min(Convert(money, Ifnull(msrp, 0))), 
    Avg(Convert(money, Ifnull(msrp, 0))),
    Max(Convert(money, Ifnull(msrp, 0))) INTO v_min_msrp, v_avg_msrp, v_max_msrp
  FROM imported_data_feed
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)

Comment: "Money" is roughly equivalent to DECIMAL(19,4) ... which is the same as NUMERIC(19,4).