# php round doesn't work as expected when inserting into database

Tags: php, mongodb, decimal

I have a problem with round and inserting into database.
Doing the following and trying to insert $y into Mongo will insert it with multiple decimals (similar to what you see from var_export below).

How can I fix this, as I need to have exactly 2 decimals.

```
<?php

$y = round(348.78 + 348.78 * 19/100, 2 );

var_dump($y);
var_export ($y);
```

This is only to display the difference on how it gets inserted into Mongo.

```
float(415.05)
415.05000000000001
```

Comment: Try with this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql

Comment: Could this be the floating-point error perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 0):

Float datatype is not a good option to represent high precision numbers. Decimal is made for that.

See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/) how (and why) to use decimal numbers with mongoDB

Comment: You forgot the link to "here"