# Numeric value out of range for decimal data type?

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `closing_price` which is `DECIMAL(6,2)`. My understanding is that this means it can take 6 digits and 2 decimal places, so the largest number that could fit in this column would be `999999.99`.

However, I am getting this error now:

```
Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'closing_price' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `stock_history` (`date`, `closing_price`, `stock_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2000-02-01, 51900.000000, 214, 2020-02-07 09:51:03, 2020-02-07 09:51:03))
```

I don't understand how this could fall out of range of `DECIMAL(6,2)`. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, or help me troubleshoot this if I am right.

I don't know why the number 51900 is showing zeros for 6 decimal places. I am getting these values from an API and a lot of them have up to 6 zeros at the end, but this is the first one that threw and error after over a million inserts.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect the maximum you can store is -9999.99 - 9999.99 see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is slightly off.  `DECIMAL(6,2)` means that there are 6 *total* places of precision, with two of those places occurring after the decimal point.  So, to store a value as large as `999999.99`, you would actually need `DECIMAL(8,2)`.

If you want a generally good type for storing currency values, you might follow the advice of [this canonical SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql), which suggests using `DECIMAL(15,2)`.