# SQL syntax error: two different platforms report different error

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am trying to make two database table and linked them together.  Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `NYSE_daily_prices_A` (
`StockSymbol` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
`StockName` varchar(100)  NOT NULL ,
`StockExchange` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (
    `StockSymbol`
)
);

CREATE TABLE `NYSE_stock_names` (
    `StockExchange` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
    `StockSymbol` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
    `date` varchar(10)  NOT NULL ,
    `StockPriceOpen` money  NOT NULL ,
    `StockPriceHigh` money  NOT NULL ,
    `StockPriceLow` money  NOT NULL ,
    `StockPriceClose` money  NOT NULL ,
    `StockVolume` int  NOT NULL ,
    `StockPriceAdjClose` money  NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE `NYSE_stock_names` ADD 
CONSTRAINT `fk_NYSE_stock_names_StockSymbol` 
FOREIGN KEY(`StockSymbol`)
REFERENCES `NYSE_daily_prices_A` (`StockSymbol`);
```

I tried to run this script in SQLiteStudio, it reports an error as following:

[image]

However, i copied the script into SQL Fiddle and it reports as following:

[image]

It really confuses me. How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not every SQL implementation is the same.  MSSQL, MySQL, SQLite, etc. all have different syntax, field types, methods, etc.  Some stuff is common between these, but some stuff isn't.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `money` field type (I don't SQLite does either), and SQLite doesn't use the keyword `CONSTRAINT` when adding foreign keys.  So, you can't really write SQL for one database type and expect it to work in another.

Comment: SQLite does not have a `money` field type either.  I think it's just reading `money` as an invalid field type and it's probably just giving you a `text` field.  See: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQLite's [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

> The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows these alterations of an
> existing table: it can be renamed; a column can be added to it; or a
> column can be dropped from it.

This means that with SQLite you can't add a foreign key constraint to an existing table.
Also, there are no `varchar` or `money` data types (they are interpreted as `TEXT` and `NUMERIC` affinities respectively), but this is not the source of the error.

In Mysql there is no `money` data type.
You can read this thread for an alternative: [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)

Your code, if you remove the backticks, is valid in SQL Server and Postgresql but not in MySql and SQLite.