# counting all records in table and putting it into a variable inside mysql itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `financial_trans` which consist of
id (AI,INT)
amount (DOUBLE)
acadYear (VARCHAR)  // probably '2020-2021'

now I want to count the similar acadYear using group by and store it into a mysql variable and my query for that is

```
SELECT s.total as total 
INTO @year 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(acadYear) as total 
    FROM  financial_trans 
    GROUP BY acadYear
) s
```

but throws an error like below,

> #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: What are you expecting by doing COUNT(acadYear) as `acadYear` is of type VARCHAR in your question?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It sounds like you want to store a table into a variable, and that is not possible.

Comment: What will the variable be used for?

Comment: I want to get the count and use it in the loop for further results...my main result is to find top 5 amount from the table for every acadYear. @FaNo_FN

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-statement `SELECT COUNT(acadYear) as total FROM  financial_trans GROUP BY acadYear` yields more then `1` row, so it can fit into variable `@year`.

That basically means that you have records for more then 1 distinct year in your `financial_trans` table. If you need to count records only for specific year, just add `WHERE acadYear = XXXX` into subquery. Or even better, `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM financial_trans WHERE acadYear = XXXX`.

Side note: `DOUBLE` is not ideal column type for financial records, you should use [DECIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)